# How to map with substring using awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files below, File1 is variable length delimited though it has a white space in between. I want to compare 3rd to 8th digit of File1 to File2, after matching fields, the 2nd column of File2 will be mapped to the 21st to 25th digit of File1 (leading zero/s). If didn't match, map it with 3rd to 8th digit (strip zeros).

Note: Retain the format.

File1

```
40001234000   00000078901
40004567000   00000078901
40001537000   00000078901
```

File2

```
1234 XXXX
1537 YYY
```

OUTPUT:

```
40001234000   0000000XXXX
40004567000   00000004567
40001537000   00000000YYY
```

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next } { key = substr($0,3,6); sub(/^0+/, "", key); emrfil = substr($0,21,5); emrfil = (key in map ? map[key] : key) OFS emrfil; print}' File2 File1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution. Supply file2 first.

```
 $ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}  
               {k=substr($1,5,4)} 
         k in a{$0=substr($0,0,length-5) 
                   substr("00000",0,5-length(a[k]))a[k]}1' file2 file1

40001234000   0000000XXXX
40004567000   00000078901
40001537000   00000000YYY
```

Note that your second line is modified even though it didn't match. Perhaps there is better way 0 padding using printf.

Comment: I have tried this but  it doesn't print **XXXX** **YYY**                   `40001234000   000000
 40004567000   00000078901
 40001537000   000000`

Comment: the order of the files is important, did you provide file2 first?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{b=+substr($1,3,6);x=a[b]?a[b]:b;$2=gensub("0*(.{11}$)","\\1",1,"0000000000"x)}1' file2 file1
40001234000 0000000XXXX
40004567000 00000004567
40001537000 00000000YYY
```

Use gawk